# Sharing a photo to LinkedIn with URL Schemes

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I'm trying to share an image from my iOS app to LinkedIn as a post - if the LinkedIn app was available/downloaded on the device. Is there a way without using the LinkedIn iOS SDK to share this content via url schemes like Instagram Stories? I could not find any solution addressing this and the documentation from LinkedIn is bare at best..

My IG Story code for reference:

```
guard let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share"), 
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) else { return }

let pasteboardItems = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": pngImage]]
let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]

UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboardItems, options: pasteboardOptions)
UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme)
```

Answer (score -1):

To share on LinkedIn, just insert the URL to the image you want to share using the URL format below...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official Microsoft Linkedin Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, here I am sharing the Google logo...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fimages%2Fbranding%2Fgooglelogo%2F2x%2Fgooglelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

The logo wasn't really sized for being an icon, but anyway, here are the results:

[image]

*Hope this helps!*